# PySpark: Replace Punctuations with Space Looping Through Columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code running successfully in PySpark:

```python
def pd(data):

    df = data
    df = df.select('oproblem')

    text_col = ['oproblem']

    for i in text_col: 

        df = df.withColumn(i, F.lower(F.col(i)))
        df = df.withColumn(i, F.regexp_replace(F.col(i), '[.,#-:;/?!\']', ' '))

    return df
```

But when I add a second column in and try to loop it, it doesn't work:

```python
def pd(data):

    df = data
    df = df.select('oproblem', 'lca')

    text_col = ['oproblem', 'lca']

    for i in text_col: 

        df = df.withColumn(i, F.lower(F.col(i)))
        df = df.withColumn(i, F.regexp_replace(F.col(i), '[.,#-:;/?!\']', ' '))

    return df
```

Below is the error I get: 
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Comment: From the code you have provided, you should not get that error. Can you [edit] the question and include the full Traceback that shows where the error is occurring? Also you could do `df = data.select('oproblem', 'lca')` and then `text_col = df.columns` to save some typing.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `df = df.select(['oproblem', 'lca'])` instead of `df = df.select('oproblem', 'lca')`

Comment: You could try this `df = df.withColumn(i, F.regexp_replace(df[i], '[.,#-:;/?!\']', ' '))`

Comment: @David the pyspark dataframe api supports it both ways. Underneath the hood I believe it will unpack the list anyway like `.select(*my_list_of_columns)`. *Edit* link to [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.select) confirms this.

Comment: @David: putting the columns in [] worked! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be `df = df.select(['oproblem', 'lca'])` instead of df = `df.select('oproblem', 'lca')`.

Better yet for code quality purposes, have the `select` statement use the `text_columns` variable, so you only have to change 1 line of code if you need to do this with more columns or if your column names change. Eg,

```
def pd(data):
    df = data
    text_col = ['oproblem', 'lca']
    df = df.select(text_col)
    ....
```